# Iteration/double iteration over a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm sorry if a similar question was answered here already, but maybe i don't know how to find it.

I have some lists who look like this:

```
A1, A6 = [157, 157, 0], [407, 157, 0]
A2, A7 = [207, 157, 0], [457, 157, 0]
```

Then i grouped them using another list:

```
A_LIST = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, AX]
```

Now i'd like to iterate over "A_LIST", taking the first and the second element out of every element from it. I tried to do it in a couple of ways:

```
def between(x, val):
    if val <= x <= val + 50:
        return True


def check_pressed():
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if click != (0, 0, 0):
    i = 0
    for i in A_LIST:
        if between(mouse_x, A_LIST[i][0]) is True and between(mouse_y, A_LIST[i][1]) is True:
```

This approach brings an error saying `unexpected type` reffering to "i". I also tried this format:
 `A_LIST[i[0]]`, but then it said `IndexError: list index out of range`. Let's say this problem is solved, then how could i "feed" this iteration with nested lists other than `A_LIST`? Like, taking 10 such sets (`B_LIST`, `C_LIST`, etc...), putting them into yet another list over which I would iterate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def between(x, val):
    if val <= x <= val + 50:
        return True
    else :
        return False  # don't forget this one

if click != (0, 0, 0):
    # i = 0  <-- don't need this line
    for i in A_LIST:
        if between(mouse_x, i[0]) and between(mouse_y, i[1]) :
            # something you like
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course, i just didn't fully understand how iterations work. I'll try to implement it to my second problem.